# How to render a map in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display list of items (projects) grouped by month-year...

For grouping I did the following and printed the results which seems fine:

```
// this gives an object with dates as keys
    const groups = filteredProjects.reduce((groups, project) => {
        //const date = project.Properties.ModificationTime.Value.split('T')[0];
        //const  month = moment(project.Properties.ModificationTime.Value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM');
        const  date = moment(project.Properties.ModificationTime.Value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM-YYYY');
        if (!groups[date]) {
            groups[date] = [];
        }
        groups[date].push(project);
        return groups;
    }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupedProjects = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
        return {
            date,
            projects: groups[date]
        };
    });
```

Now I want to render it in a way that each month will have it's own projects components. So I tried the following:

```
 {groupedProjects.map((date, arr) => (
                    <div className="inline">
                        {date}
                        {arr.map((item) =>
                            <Project
                                key={item.Name}
                                project={item}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                    ))}
```

But it's not working.
How can I render a map in such a way?

Comment: what isn't working?  please add error messages and preferably a live sample using SO snippets, JSBin or CodeSandbox.

Comment: `But it's not working` Please defined what is not working. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `map` on `groupedProjects` array like this,

```
{groupedProjects.map(({date, projects}) => (
      <div className="inline">
         {date}
         {projects.map((item) =>
             <Project
                key={item.Name}
                project={item}
             />
         )}
       </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax for using `Array.map` is wrong. Read more about the syntax on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax)

Try this, I'm destructing the object of groupedProjects in the map callback function to get the value of `date` and `projects` as `arr`

```
{groupedProjects.map(({date, projects: arr}) => (
      <div className="inline">
                    {date}
                    {arr.map((item) =>
                        <Project
                            key={item.Name}
                            project={item}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
                ))}
```